# How to solve the incompatible object shape error in python

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qutip

I'm writing this code on python but it is giving the error of incompatibility so matrix multiplication cannot take place and hence data cannot be plotted.

```py
# !pip3 install qutip
import qutip as qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
ω = qt.Qobj(np.arange(0.0,1.1,0.1))
Δ=o=0.1
ℏ=1.05457182*10**(-34)
σx = qt.sigmax()
σy = qt.sigmay()
σz = qt.sigmaz()
H = ℏ*(Δ*σx + o*σy + ω*σz)/2
plt.plot(ω,H)
plt.show()
```

....

```
TypeError: Incompatible Qobj shapes.
```

Code failed because the ω variable was a Qobj with dimensions [[2], [1]], while the Pauli matrices σx, σy, and σz had dimensions [[2, 2]]. This resulted in a shape mismatch when performing the matrix multiplication in the Hamiltonian definition. so how to create w with above range having shape[[2],[2]]

Comment: If you want matrix multiplication, are you sure you don't want `ω @ σz` instead? `Δ` and `o` are scalars, so `*` is appropriate.

Comment: Right.  Just in case you missed that, `*` is element-wise multiplication.  `@` is the matrix multiplication operator.

Comment: when I'm using @ its giving error(unsupported operand error.